# Least greedy square

Tags: geometry, rectangles

There are $n$ squares of $m$ different colors. Squares of the same color are interior disjoint, but squares of different colors may intersect.

For every square, define its "greed" as the maximum number of squares of a single color that it intersects. For example, in the figure below, the top-left red square has a greed of 1 because it intersects 1 green square; the bottom-right red square has a greed of 4 becaues it intersects 4 green squres (in addition to 1 blue square); the other two red squares have a greed of 2.

[image]

MY QUESTION IS: What is the minimum greed that a single square can have, in the worst case?

**4** is an upper bound, because the smallest of all squares has a greed of at most 4. This is because, when a square intersects a larger square, at least one corner of the smaller square must be covered. Since a square has 4 corners, it can intersect at most 4 larger squares that are disjoint, i.e., at most 4 squares per color.

**2** is a lower bound, as shown by the construction below, where all squares have a greed of 2:

[image]

So, the question is whether there is always a square with a greed of at most 2? Or at most 3?

Comment: Why could a large red square not intersect, say, 15 blue squares, all lined up along its right-hand edge, but not intersecting each other? Perhaps you need to be clearer for us on what the constraints on the squares might be.

Comment: Or, what if all squares have distinct interiors?

Comment: @John If I understand the problem correctly, then the question is on $$\sup_{\text{instance }I}\quad\min_{\text{square } s \in I}\quad\mathrm{greed}(s).$$

Comment: So to rephrase the question: Is there a (nonempty) arrangement of squares where each square has greed at least four (or at least three)?

Comment: @John If a large red square intersects 15 blue squares, then the greed of the large red is 15, but one of the blue squares may have a smaller greed. I am looking for a single square, of a single color, that has the smallest greed.

Comment: @EddieE. if there is a square that does not intersect any other square, then its greed is 0, which is the "best" case. My question is about the minimum greed in the worst case, as explained formally by dtldarek.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen yes. In other words: Is there an arrangement of squraes where each square intersects at least 3/4 squares of at least one other color?

Comment: @Listing The question stipulates that they must be squares, i.e. side lengths are equal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Partial solution:** Here is an example for lowerbound of $\mathbf{3}$:

[image: squares]

and my hypothesis is that this is it (assuming finite number of squares and colors).

I hope this helps $\ddot\smile$

Comment: Nice! Now it only remains to check the case of 4.

Comment: The case of 4 is probably worth a new question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/646150/colorful-squares-arrangement